# Modify selected property in select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, selector

I'm building a select with several options from my php script using pattemplate.

But no matter what I do, the selected option shows in the dom tree like this:

```
<select id="academicYear">
<option value="1516">2015-2016</option> 
<option value="1415">2014-2015</option> 
<option selected="" value="1314">2013-2014</option> 
<option value="1213">2012-2013</option> 
</select>
```

Is there any way using dom - javascript - jquery to turn:

```
<option selected="" value="1314">2013-2014</option>
```

Into:

```
<option selected value="1314">2013-2014</option>
```

?

The reason why I need the change: with selected="" I don't get any selection when my select shows in the dialog window where I present it. When I turn it into just select with Firebug and Chrome debug bar the selection works.

Thans a ton!

Comment: Yes, you could use something like `$('option[value="1314"]').prop('selected', true);`, but it seems quite ugly. I don't know anything about pattemplate but you should stress to make it generate the correct html

Comment: The selected attribute is a boolean attribute and it's mere presence indicates that it's true, so in theory even `selected=""` should work (works for me in Chrome).

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle to illustrate your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the id for faster and safer selector:

```
$('#academicYear option[value="1314"]').prop('selected', true);
```

The right html sintaxis is:

```
<option selected="selected" value="1314">2013-2014</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe setting the value of select will alter that property correctly for you.  Otherwise if you still need to change the selected property...

```
$('option[value="1314"]').prop('selected', true);
```